# How to wait for another activity to start with Espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

How can I make a test that waits for an Activity to start whenever a button is clicked?

My test is really simple:

```
public void testStartsNewActivity() {
   onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
   // assert new Activity is launched
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Do you want to wait till the activity, that is supposed to be opened after the click, will be launched?

Answer (score 1):

Asserting that a new activity has been launched is as easy as asserting that a view belonging to that new activity is displayed on the screen.

Check [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso) for more samples. Additional info:

> By default, Espresso waits for UI events in the current message queue to process and default AsyncTasks* to complete before it moves on to the next test operation. This should address the majority of application/test synchronization in your application.

Thus, given your "really simple" test case, I'm assuming there's no waiting on custom resource loading and asserting that a view is displayed should be enough.

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check that an intent was indeed sent, using [espresso-intents library](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/intents). Also you can check if this intent contains all the needed extras and that the intent has the right action. This is a more flexible answer than the previous one, because it doesn't rely on views, which you may not have access to, for example you can check that you launch some system activity (some settings) or an activity from a library that you don't have the direct access to. So the example code may look like:

```
public void testStartsNewActivity() {
   onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
   intended(allOf(hasComponent(ActivityToBeOpened.class.getName())));
   // or if you know the package
   intended(toPackage("com.android.phone"))
}
```

If you wanted to know how exactly to **wait** for an activity to be shown I recommend you [this](http://www.douevencode.com/articles/2019-02/espresso-wait-for-activity-visible/) guide.